# How to save date time format in CakePHP (pass the date from JS to CakePHP)

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a datetime variable in JS which is:

```
var date_start   = dateFormat(newJobForm.time_start, "yyyy-mm-dd-HH-MM"); 
var date_end     = dateFormat(newJobForm.time_end, "yyyy-mm-dd-HH-MM");
```

The main problem is: I can't show the minutes only

When I pass my dates to PHP's `date()` function, because of the `:` between `H` and `i`, it won't save it. I tried to `explode()` it with `-` but it didn't work.

The URL is: `my_controller/abcd^5^2012-10-15-15-15^2012-10-18-17-30` and my controller in CakePHP action to take the time from JS is:

```
$time_start          = $explode_item[2];                 
$time_end            = $explode_item[3]; 

$dateStart = strtotime ( date('Y-m-d H:i', $time_start) ) ;
            $dateStartArray['Y'] = date ( 'Y' , $dateStart );
            $dateStartArray['m'] = date ( 'm' , $dateStart );
            $dateStartArray['d'] = date ( 'd' , $dateStart );
            $dateStartArray['H'] = date ( 'H' , $dateStart );
            $dateStartArray['i'] = date ( 'i' , $dateStart );
```

Comment: I got the answer:                                          thank you for your help every one!! controller should be

    date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime ('+1 hour', strtotime (date("Y-m-d H:i",$time_end))));
and we need to convert the time to Echop in js

    var d = new Date(value);
               var epochtime = (d.getTime()-d.getMilliseconds())/1000; 

Done ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer: 

controller should be

```
$dateStart = date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime ('+1 hour', strtotime (date("Y-m-d H:i",$time_start))));
$dateEnd   = date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime ('+1 hour', strtotime (date("Y-m-d H:i",$time_end))));
```

and we need to convert the time to Echop in js

```
var d = new Date(value); var epochtime = (d.getTime()-d.getMilliseconds())/1000;
```

Done ! :)